# How to get media device ids that user selected in request permission dialog?

Tags: javascript

I want my users to choose the desired audio input device and video input device. On first request to getUserMedia the user will see a dialog like this (Opera on Windows):

[image]

The user can select the desired devices in this popup dialog. But is there any way to get the selected deviceIds that the user selected out of this dialog? The promise returns access to a stream, but the id/name of this stream has nothing to do with the devices.

I've used this example and tried to modify it: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

My purpose is to synchronize the selected devices in the popup with the website selects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can obtain the device id using `.getSettings().deviceId` on MediaTrack object, then use this device id to match against devices in `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`, once matched you'll get an object back with following properties:

```
deviceId:"<device id>"
groupId:""
kind:"videoinput"
label:"Integrated Webcam (<id>)"
```

A sample getUserMedia which obtains MediaTracks objects...

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } })
.then(function(stream) {
  var tracks = stream.getTracks();
  for(var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++){
     GetDevice(tracks[i].getSettings().deviceId)
  }
})
.catch(function(err) {
  /* handle the error */
});
```

and a sample function which will match the ids to get the selected devices...

```
function GetDevice(id){
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(function(devices) {
    devices.forEach(function(device) {

      if(device.deviceId == id){
          console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label != undefined ? device.label : 'Default');
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
  });
}
```

Check my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrsnpp93/1/) for sample code.

Comment: @SuperNova No worries, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Helloween is over and I tested your answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: On Chromium deviceId is set, but on Firefox I'm getting undefined. It's supposed to be supported though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/deviceId. That's with my code. I couldn't get your JSFiddle to do anything.